# Rendering with map twice leads to error in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
    <View style={styles.card} >
        {store.crud.list.map(function(element, index){
            return (
                <View style={styles.wrapper}>
                    {element.map(function(number, index){
                        return(
                            <View>
                                <Text style={styles.number}>
                                    {element}
                                </Text>
                            </View>
                        );
                    })}
                </View>
            );
        })}
    </View>
```

I have this react-native element and it seems that it won't render, the second render seems to break the code, because I remove it and just render element, it works fine.

**I am getting the error:**

```
TypeError: "Text constructor: 'new' is required"
React 12
unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.development.js:643
React 6
```

Also, the content of store.crud is `{ list: [[2,3,3,3,3,4],[3,1,1,1,1,1]] }`. It's simple number refers to the number and element refers to the array.

The following works fine:

```
    <View style={styles.card} >
        {store.crud.list.map(function(element, index){
            return (
                <View style={styles.wrapper}>
                     {element}
                </View>
            );
        })}
    </View>
```

However, as I've said, I want to style every number inside element.

EDIT: I also tried this and it doesn't work even though it works on Codesandbox:

```
    const ConfigScreen = () => {

    let store = {
        crud:{
          list:[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,23,45,65,8]]
         }
       };

       return (
         <View style={styles.card} >
       {store.crud.list.map(function (element, index) {
           return (
               <View style={styles.wrapper}>
                   {element.map(function (number, index) {
                       return (
                           <View>
                               <Text style={styles.number}>
                                   {number}
                               </Text>
                           </View>
                       );
                   })}
               </View>
           );
       })}
   </View>
       );

};
```

Is it an issue with the expo client/metro bundler?

I entered expo start --no-https and then clicked on "Run in web browser".

Comment: You have a digit missing in the second array , last digit.

Comment: Sorry, I was just giving an example.

Comment: I thought that was the real data and maybe that's why the problem occured.

Comment: list: [
        [1,2,2,4,3,6]
    ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

class App extends Component {
   store = {
     crud:{
       list:[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,23,45,65,8]]
      }
    };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.card} >
    {this.store.crud.list.map(function (element, index) {
        return (
            <View style={styles.wrapper}>
                {element.map(function (number, index) {
                    return (
                        <View>
                            <Text style={styles.number}>
                                {number}
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                    );
                })}
            </View>
        );
    })}
</View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  app: {
    marginHorizontal: "auto",
    maxWidth: 500
  },
  logo: {
    height: 80
  },
  header: {
    padding: 20
  },
  title: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: "1.5rem",
    marginVertical: "1em",
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  text: {
    lineHeight: "1.5em",
    fontSize: "1.125rem",
    marginVertical: "1em",
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  link: {
    color: "#1B95E0"
  },
  code: {
    fontFamily: "monospace, monospace"
  }
});

export default App;
```

This code works as [image: expected].  Also, you can try to run this code on this site https://codesandbox.io/s/q4qymyp2l6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: What's the difference? It doesn't matter if I swap element to number. It won't output anything.

Comment: You were setting {element} in <Text>, which is array. I have used the object from it.

Comment: Yeah, but that's not the issue.

Comment: I am able to get the desired result. I have attached screenshot please check.

Comment: Ah, wait. It doesn't work either. Is it a problem related to the expo client (web)?

Comment: I entered expo start --no-https and then clicked on "Run in web browser".

Answer (score 0):

Try to use flat list, see expo example - https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/react-native/flatlist/